# Could not load file or assembly 'MediaToolkit'

Tags: c#

I want to grab the thumbnail from a video, and in code everything is well, but when I build the msi file and run my application I get the error message:

```
    Error getting video.System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load 
    file or assembly 'MediaToolkit, Version=1.1.0.1, Culture=neutral, 
    PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot 
    find the file specified.
    File name: 'MediaToolkit, Version=1.1.0.1, Culture=neutral, 
    PublicKeyToken=null'
```

It happened when I tried to get the video duration.

```
    private TimeSpan GetDurationOfMediaFile(string filePath)
    {
        var inputFile = new MediaFile { Filename = filePath };

        using (var engine = new Engine())
            engine.GetMetadata(inputFile);
        return inputFile.Metadata.Duration;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be missing a reference or a nuget-package. I'm not sure why the compiler doesn't warn you about this. Similar things usually happen when something is assumed to be in the GAC and your application doesn't download it. Check which namespace/dll the MediaToolkit comes from and check your output folder (bin/Release OR Debug) if it is there.

Answer (score 0):

Add the nuget to your project:

```
Install-Package MediaToolkit -Version 1.1.0.1
```

Make sure to add this nuget into the correct project in your solution.

Comment: I have already installed to my Aproj
PM> Install-Package MediaToolkit
'MediaToolkit 1.1.0.1' already installed.
Adding 'MediaToolkit 1.1.0.1' to Aproj.
Successfully added 'MediaToolkit 1.1.0.1' to Aproj.

Comment: Also, I see that appropriate dll exist in my 'bin\Release' folder but when I build the msi file and then install it, it the application folder this file does not exist, and I don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

I create an MSI file using Wix, and in the project I also used a .NSI file in which we write the list of DLLs with which it will be created